# XSLT filtering by item value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sum items only if the code is unique.

I have this XML:

```xml
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Brambory 10 kg</NAME>
    <CODE>4</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>23</AMOUNT>
    <COUNT>19</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Česnek 1 kg</NAME>
    <CODE>89</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>11</AMOUNT>
    <COUNT>10</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Neděle - Příbram</NAME>
    <CODE>SHIPPING140</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>16</AMOUNT>
    <COUNT>16</COUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Úterý - Liberec</NAME>
    <CODE>SHIPPING122</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
    <COUNT>10</COUNT>
</ITEM>
```

I would like to sum only amounts of goods, if the delivery place is like `SHIPPING122`.

I use this XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="itemkey" match="ITEM" use="concat(NAME, CODE)"/>
<xsl:template match="/ORDERS">
  <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemkey', concat(NAME, CODE))[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ITEM">   
    <xsl:copy>      
        <xsl:variable name="curr-group" select="key('itemkey', concat(NAME, CODE))" />  
       <xsl:copy-of select="CODE|NAME"/>        
        <AMOUNT>         
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($curr-group/AMOUNT)"/>        
        </AMOUNT>       
    </xsl:copy>         
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works perfect, but I have sum of all goods. But I only need sum if the CODE of delivery is SHIPPING122. I try to filter by test `CODE = 'SHIPPING107'`, but it doesnt work.

Prefered XML output:

```xml
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Brambory 10 kg</NAME>
    <CODE>4</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Česnek 1 kg</NAME>
    <CODE>89</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>3</AMOUNT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <NAME>Úterý - Liberec</NAME>
    <CODE>SHIPPING122</CODE>
    <AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
    <COUNT>10</COUNT>
</ITEM>
```

When is delivery place with `CODE = 'SHIPPING122'` I would like to sum goods Brambory, Česnek, etc. only from this delivery place, not from all orders (all delivery places).

Comment: Do want no AMOUNT at all at all if the CODE is not SHIPPING122? Or do you want no ITEM result if the CODE is not SHIPPING? Consider to show the result you want to output and if you have an attempt in XSLT that fails then show us that attempt and tell us exactly how it failed, either which error you get or in which way the output is wrong.

Comment: When is delivery place with CODE = 'SHIPPING122' I would like to sum goods Brambory, Česnek, etc. only from this delivery place, not from all orders (all delivery places). Thank you

Comment: So the input has `<AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>` and the output `<AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>` as well? Do the samples show any data at all where you need and want to group and sum?

Comment: Sum is value from all orders, I nedd value of only orders, that have `CODE = 'SHIPPING122' ` Tahnk you

Comment: Do we have to assume that the snippet file you showed us above needs be enclosed in a pair of tags `<ORDERS></ORDERS>` in order to become a well-formed XML file?

Comment: Yes, of course :-)

Comment: Ivan, I think it will be easier to help you if you provide full input/output examples (with `ORDERS` tags and some sum to do)

Comment: Full XML input is here [link](https://www.farmapesema.cz/export/orders.xml?patternId=8&hash=dea0602a8029ff268f06b9c5c2aced98d8b1e0a5255edb5866fd8bc80068425b)

Comment: Thank you for your replay, now it works great. I would like to do only one modification, it is possible to use `order="descending"` or `<xsl:sort>` ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure which data you want to group and sum but to show one version where you include your condition in a predicate is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="itemkey" match="ITEM[CODE = 'SHIPPING122']" use="concat(NAME, CODE)"/>
  <xsl:template match="/ORDERS">
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ITEM[CODE != 'SHIPPING122'] | descendant::ITEM[CODE = 'SHIPPING122'][generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemkey', concat(NAME, CODE))[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ITEM[CODE != 'SHIPPING122']">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="CODE | NAME | AMOUNT"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ITEM[CODE = 'SHIPPING122']">
    <xsl:copy>      
        <xsl:variable name="curr-group" select="key('itemkey', concat(NAME, CODE))" />  
       <xsl:copy-of select="CODE|NAME"/>        
        <AMOUNT>         
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($curr-group/AMOUNT)"/>        
        </AMOUNT>       
    </xsl:copy>         
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will only group and sum any `ITEM`s with the same `NAME` and `CODE` where the `CODE` is `'SHIPPING122'`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, now it works great. I would like to do only one modification, it is possible to use `order="descending"` or `<xsl:sort>` ? Thank you

Comment: If the original question is solved by this answer then consider accepting. For new problems raise a new question.